# rxjs - combining inner observables after filtering

Tags: rxjs, rxjs6

I call backend that respond with:

```
[
  "https://some-url.com/someData1.json",
  "https://some-url.com/someData2.json"
]
```

Each JSON can have following schema:

```
{
  "isValid": boolean,
  "data": string
}
```

I want to get array with all data, that have isValid is set to true

```
backend.get(url)
    .pipe(
        mergeMap((urls: []) =>
            urls.map((url: string) =>
                backend.get(url)
                    .pipe(
                        filter(response => response.isValid),
                        map(response => response.data)
                    )
            )
        ),
        combineAll()
    )
```

When both .json have "isValid" set to true, I get array with both data.
But when one of them has "isValid" set to false observable never completes.

I could use mergeAll instead of combineAll, but then I receive stream of single data not collection of all data.

Is there any better way to filter out observable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said, the inner observable never emits, because `filter` does not forward the only value that is ever emitted by the `backend.get` observable. In that case, the operator subscribing on that observable - in your case `combineAll` - will also never receive any value and cannot ever emit itself.

What I would do is just move the filtering and mapping to `combineAll` by providing a project function, like that:

```
backend.get(url)
    .pipe(
        mergeMap((urls: string[]) =>
            urls.map((url: string) => backend.get(url))
        ),
        combineAll(responses =>
            responses
                .filter(response => response.isValid)
                .map(response => response.data)
        )
    )
```

See if that works for you ;)

Comment: thanks, in fact filtering will be done after another Observable is produced, thats why I wanted leve combineAll clear and thought to filter out Observable But it seems that using combineAll would not be good idea :)

Answer (score 0):

```
import { forkJoin, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

interface IRes {
  isValid: boolean;
  data: string;
}

interface IResValid {
  isValid: true;
  data: string;
}

function isValid(data: IRes): data is IResValid {
  return data.isValid;
}

const res1$: Observable<IRes> = backend.get(url1);
const res2$: Observable<IRes> = backend.get(url2);

// When all observables complete, emit the last emitted value from each.
forkJoin([res1$, res2$])
  .pipe(map((results: IRes[]) => results.filter(isValid)))
  .subscribe((results: IResValid[]) => console.log(results));
```

Comment: This may be a correct answer, but it could be improved by adding a description of what it does and how it answers the question. For more information read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer